# How can I know whether my laserjet is using color toner to print black?

Tags: printing, printer, colors, network-printer, hp-laserjet

I've got an HP M176n all-in-one color laserjet printer.  For quite a while now it's been displaying "black toner low" messages but I've been ignoring them, preferring only to replace the toner cartridge when I feel the black is faded enough.  However, the black still seems fine and I'm starting to wonder whether the printer is compensating for the lack of black toner by combining the colors to create black instead.  I generally print black and white stuff the vast majority of the time.

Might the printer use the color toner instead if black is low, and how can I tell whether it's doing it?

Comment: Black is not made from the other colors.

Comment: I dont "do" HP printers, but according to https://support.hp.com/nz-en/document/ish_2453626-1757228-16 its possible that the ink level is a page count and could be very inaccurate. HP invest a lot of effort in getting customers to waste money on ink/toner, so this is not surprising.

Comment: @music2myear Theoretically, it is.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model

Comment: "... gives an imperfect black color". No, it really isn't.

Comment: "Although a combination of 100% cyan, magenta, and yellow inks should, in theory, completely absorb the entire visible spectrum of light and produce a perfect black, practical inks fall short of their ideal characteristics" - in theory, it really is.